# Ajax - Function to check if url exists before send request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am writing a function to grab a json file from a website/server and save it in local storage with the code:

```
function donators() {
    var jsonURL = "http://mywebsite.com/donators.json";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", jsonURL, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            localDataStore.set("fb_donators", xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

The above code works perfectly fine when the json file can be reached, but if my server goes down and the file cannot be reached my script halts at the line with xhr.send() with the error:

```
GET http://mywebsite.com/donators.json net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Is there a way I can detect check if url can be reached before the send request to stop the send the request and allow the rest of my script to continue to run instead of getting halted at xhr.send()?

Thanks!

Comment: The script shouldn't halt.  It should just have an error which you can detect and handle.  And, no you can't check if a URL exists from the browser without requesting it and see what you get back (successful data or error).

Comment: ah, thank you - there was another error in processing the data stored in localStorage as "" was stored

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `try` block for this. It still requires the HTTP request, but it will fail gracefully and you can handle the error any way you'd like.

```
function donators() {
    var jsonURL = "http://mywebsite.com/donators.json";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", jsonURL, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            localDataStore.set("fb_donators", xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhr.timeout = 5000;
    xhr.ontimeout = function() {
        alert( 'The operation timed out.' );
    }
    try { xhr.send(); } catch( err ) {
        alert( 'Error getting data: ' + err.message );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! I was able to use this and what jfriend00 said to solve my problem.

Comment: Does this catch timeouts too? Cant seem to get the exception to fire for timeouts. I guess I need to manually set the ontimeout method.

Comment: @DavidLannan Good catch! Timeouts aren't considered "errors" according to XHR, so an additional handler `ontimeout` must be used. I've updated my example to work with that situation.